# Problema com Imagem Responsiva

Tags: css3

```
img {
background-image: url(../img/slides/11.jpg);
max-width:100%;
height:auto;
}
```

Quando coloco o código acima, acontece o seguinte erro:
[image]

A imagem (como na foto) vai para cima.

Sendo que sem o código fica assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que posso fazer?

```css
   #home .bg-img {
 padding: 100px;
 -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
 box-sizing: content-box;
 position: absolute;
 top: -50px;
 left: -50px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center center;
 }

    #home .bg-img-1 {
 background-image: url(../img/slides/11.jpg);}
```

```html
<div class="bg-img bg-img-1"></div>
```

Comment: Coloquei no final como está os códigos no html e css

Comment: Não consegui reproduzir o defeito. Poderia fornecer um [exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0):

Trabalhe o background-image somente no pai da tag img.

No caso da tag img, deixe o caminho da imagem no atributo src normalmente,
e no CSS, retire a opacidade completamente, assim a tag img se encarrega de preencher o espaço necessário da imagem, enquanto o pai, com o background-image, se encarrega de exibir a imagem de forma responsiva dentro dos limites.

No seu exemplo, o único espaço disponível era o padding de 100px. por isso o background-image tentou preencher somente esse espaço.

Código CSS:

```
#home .bg-img {
padding: 100px;
-webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
-moz-box-sizing: content-box;
box-sizing: content-box;
position: absolute;
top: -50px;
left: -50px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center center;
}

#home .bg-img-1 { background-image: url(../img/slides/11.jpg); }
#home .bg-img img{ opacity: 0; }
```

Código HTML:

```
<div class="bg-img bg-img-1">
<img src="../img/slides/11.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Ainda não funcionou...

Comment: Precisa realmente do position: absolute;?

Comment: Mesmo se eu tirar, não faz diferença

Comment: Tenta postar a sua aplicação ou apenas essa parte no Codepen ou outro meio para analisarmos melhor